# Python CSV to JSON: Why is JSON significantly larger than the CSV file and how can it be fixed?

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas, dictionary

I've run into an interesting problem when converting a CSV file to JSON.  I generate a CSV file based on output from an SQLite query and write this to the hard drive.

I then load the CSV file into my script using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df_var  = pd.read_csv('input.csv',header=0, low_memory=False)
```

I used the *low_memory* option since the dataframe consists of multiple datatypes.  I am not opposed to storing everything as a string value if anyone suggests that.

Each row of the dataframe represents one record (each record has 144 fields/columns), so I strip off one row at a time and feed it into a class I built to convert that row into a dictionary (this is inside the class):

```
class CSVParser:


    def __init__(self, recordid, tjson={}):

        self.recordid = recordid
        self.json     = tjson

    def create_json(self, df):

        o_dict = {
                    'root': {
                        'id': {
                            'field1':df['field1'],
                            'field2':df['field2'],
                            'field3':self.recordid,
                        },

                        'core': {
                            'field1':df['field1'],
                            'field2':df['field2'],
                            'field3':df['field3'],
                            'field4':df['field4'],
                            'field5':df['field5'],
                            'field6':df['field6'],
                        },

                        #REMAINING RECORDS LEFT OUT FOR BREVITY

                    }
                }

        self.json.append(o_dict)
```

From here I write the JSON to disk

```
def write_json(self):
    #if self is not empty write JSON to file

    if self.json:
        filename = 'output/' + self.recordid + '_output.json'
        with open(filename,'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(self.json,outfile, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
        print('JSON saved to drive')
    else:
        print('\nEmpty JSON\n')
        return(self.json)
```

Here's what I get then, suppose I run just 500 records the CSV file will be around 23MB in size with the resulting JSON at ~190MB!  Surely I am adding some unintentional formatting that I just can't seem to find.  My belief was the JSON file would yield a smaller file size than the CSV.

Last bit of info, I originally used an OrderedDict to run this but when I saw the resulting JSON file size I thought maybe the OrderedDict was adding some formatting that was increasing the size a lot, after moving back to a dictionary not much changed with the end file size.

Please let me know if you need any other information and I'll be sure to provide it.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: How about you open both files and see where the difference in size comes from?

Comment: Turn off indentation, for one thing. Prettified JSON with one object per line and four-space indentation can have a lot of whitespace in it.

Comment: Also in csv, you define field names as headers, but in json you need to repeat field names for each object. I think that is where your extra space usage is going

Comment: I tried the advice of getting rid of the indents and by leaving the separators in there, it essentially minified the JSON file.  This saved some space.  @VivekKumar I think you are right here.  It looks like the redundancy in the key values is what's killing my space.  I was hoping there was something I overlooked, but I think you got it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is for a simple reason that the JSON has a lot more than the CSV.

If you look at the generated JSON you will see that it has a lot of keys like field1, field2 etc. This is because JSON doesn't have the notion of a schema. Every entry can be different. These extra characters occupy space (1 byte per letter). These probably add up to more data that your actual data.

Apart from this JSON also has characters like [,],{,},: and , 
These are essential because JSON is also very human readable.

Finally if you want to dump the data in less space you can space but still want to use JSON, try to shorten the keys. Like use f1 instead of field1.

You can also convert the JSON to be a list of list rather than a dictionary.
Because you have the scheme available from the SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the tips here on the field names.  It's a good way to save on the file size a bit.  Some of my keys are on the longer side due to pulling from the SQLite fields.  I can reduce some of the key names and provide a new data dictionary where needed.  In the end, due to file transfer rates/costs I decided to add gzip compression to move the data, this saved significantly on the space, from 3Gb down to 100Mb.  I would like to remove some of the unnecessary data at the moment but all of it is being requested by the end-user.  Another fix for another day.  Thanks again!

Comment: You can probably make an index ( dictionary which maps the real names to very small names) and use the small names. This way you can preserve the actual field names too